# Put Quasar q-checkbox Answers into an Array in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, checkbox, quasar-framework

i have an array called answers. I want to store the answers from different Questions in that array. One Question type that i have is [q-checkbox](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/checkbox/) to select multiple answers. Because its possible to select multiple answers they must be stored in an array. I cant find a way to store the values from the "multiple answers array" in the answers array.

It should look like something like this:
answers = [question1Answer, question2Answer, [question3Answer1, question3Answer2],...]

I tried it with this attempt:

```html
<q-checkbox v-model="answers[questionObject.id]" :val="multiSelectAnswers" :label="multiSelectAnswers" color="red"/>
```

but this isnt working. "answers[questionObject.id]" just inserts a true or false into the answers array.

I also tried storing the Multiple Select answers with there unique ids in a different array and transfer them with a watch function into the main array. But the problem of this was that "unticking" options didnt removed them from the array.

This is the full diff for the question type multiple select:

```html
  <div v-if="questionObject.type == 'multi-select'" class="items-center">
    <div class="text-h6">{{ questionObject.question }}</div>
    <div v-for="(multiSelectAnswers, index) in questionObject.possibleAnswers" :key="index">
        <q-checkbox v-model="answers[questionObject.id]" :val="multiSelectAnswers" :label="multiSelectAnswers" color="red"/>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I created the answers array with:

```js
    const answers = ref([])
```

This is how a single Question is Stored:
{
"id": "1",
"type": "multi-select",
"question": "xyz?",
"possibleAnswers": [
"x",
"y",
"z"
],
"minSelected": 0,
"maxSelected": 0
},

I would be very greatfull if someone finds a way to solve this issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create a nested array.  The v-model needs to bind to the nested array indices

```html
<q-checkbox
  v-model="answers[questionObject.id][index]"
  :val="multiSelectAnswers"
  :label="multiSelectAnswers"
  color="red"
/>
```

The nested array will also need to be initialized so the above code doesn't error.

```js
const answers = ref([]);
answers.value[questionObject.value.id] = [];
```

#### Edit:

given `questionObject` is actually an individual object created in a v-for loop, and given the v-for array is called `questions`, the initialization can be done with a for loop

```js
const answers = ref([]);
questions.value.forEach((questionObject) => {
  answers.value[questionObject.id] = [];
});
```

Comment: i also tried this but without initializing the nested array. But there is one Problem "questionObject" is created in a for loop in the template section. I create the answers array in the script section so questionObject isnt reachable from the script section. Is there a way to initialize it when den div is called?

Comment: whatever array `questionObject` comes from I assume you _do_ have access to in the script?  if that is the case, see the edit I just made to my answer